# How to dynamically change the layout of my cell in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a TableView and I implemented this method to return a Cell for each row:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And in my Cell, I have a ImageView to the left of the cell, follow by a Label to the right of the ImageView.

However, in come case, I want to make the ImageView disappears and have just a Label and move the Label to where the ImageView were.

So I add the following condition in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
if (//imageView should disappear)
{
    cell.image.frame = CGRectMake(cell.image.frame.origin.x,
                                      cell.image.frame.origin.y,
                                      0, 0);  // set widht and height of image to 0.
    cell.label.frame= CGRectMake(cell.image.frame.origin.x,
                                 cell.image.frame.origin.y,
                                 cell.label.frame.size.width,
                                 cell.label.frame.size.height);
    // move the label to where the image were.
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

I step thru the code in the debugger, it does get executed. But when I run it, nothing get changed. The image view still there and the Label still to the right of Image View.

Can you please tell me what am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using auto layout in your cell? If so, you shouldn't be setting any frames, but adjusting constraints instead.

Comment: By the way, this behavior of having an optional image view is the behavior of the default tableview cell, so absolutely no extra coding is needed (other than setting the `cell?.imageView.image` property to `nil` if there's no image). If there's something that you don't like about how this default tableview cell works, fine, create your own, but don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to...

Comment: Thanks. @rdelmar. Adjusting constraints works.